# How do i generate 30 random numbers using standard deviation and mean

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate 30 random numbers using standard deviation and mean.
I tried a few mathematical formulas and expressions but didn't get what I wanted.
Can you help me ?

```
def create_yemek_list(x):

    mean= 120
    std = 1
    x = np.linspace(mean+ 3 * std, mean- 3 * std, 100)
    return x
```

Comment: Answering questions like this is simply a matter of *knowing what things are called*, and then searching for the relevant terms.

Comment: See the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module.  Either [`random.gauss`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.gauss) or [`random.normalvariate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.normalvariate).

Comment: There should be a better duplicate for this, but also questions like this are [best answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) by [doing appropriate research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+normal+distribution).